# How do I list all procedures that can be used in SQL queries in Informix

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

In Informix, I can create procedures like these:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (i INT);

CREATE PROCEDURE p1()
RETURNING INT
  RETURN 1;
END PROCEDURE;

CREATE PROCEDURE p2()
RETURNING INT
  INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);
  RETURN 1;
END PROCEDURE;
```

Now, I can call both procedures using the `EXECUTE` syntax:

```sql
EXECUTE PROCEDURE p1();
EXECUTE PROCEDURE p2();
```

But I can only execute the first one in a `SELECT` statement:

```sql
-- Works
SELECT p1();
-- Fails with SQL Error [IX000]: Illegal SQL statement in SPL routine.
SELECT p2();
```

[This is documented here in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=block-restrictions-spl-routines-in-data-manipulation-statements).

I cannot seem to distinguish the two types of procedure from the dictionary, e.g.

```sql
SELECT procname, isproc
FROM sysprocedures
WHERE procname IN ('p1', 'p2');
```

Yields:

```
|procname|isproc|
|--------|------|
|p1      |f     |
|p2      |f     |
```

Other fields from `sysprocname` are also not helpful. How can I recognise a procedure that contains such "illegal SQL statements"? (I'd like to avoid parsing the `sysprocbody` contents)

Comment: There isn't a simple way to determine such procedures. Procedures containing some DDL statements — CREATE, DROP, ALTER, etc — cannot be called from a SELECT statement. A procedure containing a DML statement other than SELECT cannot be called from a SELECT statement. The page you link to lists a surprisingly small subset of the statements; I'm deeply suspicious that the list is not complete. If the list is to be believed, you can create tables, indexes, views and casts in a stored procedure called from a SELECT statement, and empirical evidence shows that you _can_ create a table like that.

Comment: That all means that parsing `sysprocbody` to determine what's allowed and what isn't is anything but trivial.  You have to concatenate the text from multiple entries to get the body of the procedure (because words can be split across entries).  You have to determine whether the statements contained are allowed.  You can use simple heuristics (if it contains 'create' — case-insensitively — it is not allowed) which are pessimistic (CREATE TABLE is OK; CREATE AGGREGATE is not).  Or you can worry about abuse of keywords — no, don't worry about that.  But it is not trivial.

Comment: AFAICT from a cursory study of the source code, there are banned statements not listed on the linked page (CREATE/DROP NAMED ROW TYPE, for instance).  And the test is done while the SELECT is being analyzed — it isn't recorded explicitly in the system catalog whether or not the procedure can be called in a SELECT statement.  So there's no direct way to find out from the system catalog whether the stored procedure is usable.